# R plot jumping confidence region

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a plot of confidence bands, which update every year.

Here is an example of the plot I'm trying to create: 
[image: graph from excel]

Some reproducible data is below:

```
x_axis <- seq(1,24)
confidence_low_yr_1 <- c(seq(40,by=15, length.out = 12),rep(NA,12))
confidence_high_yr_1 <- c(seq(140,by=15, length.out = 12),rep(NA,12))
confidence_low_yr_2 <- c(rep(NA,11),seq(250,by=15, length.out = 13))
confidence_high_yr_2 <- c(rep(NA,11),seq(315,by=15, length.out = 13))
```

When I tried to plot the lines, I received an error about mismatching lengths.. I'm guessing this had to do with the NA values. I'm not sure how to go about this, so any help would be appreciated. Another issue is filling in the are between the lines.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Can you share the code that you tried?

Comment: look into goem_ribbon() its pretty straightforward if you have used ggplot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved with `geom_ribbon()`.

```
library(ggplot2)

x_axis <- seq(1,24)
confidence_low_yr_1 <- c(seq(40,by=15, length.out = 12),rep(NA,12))
confidence_high_yr_1 <- c(seq(140,by=15, length.out = 12),rep(NA,12))
confidence_low_yr_2 <- c(rep(NA,11),seq(250,by=15, length.out = 13))
confidence_high_yr_2 <- c(rep(NA,11),seq(315,by=15, length.out = 13))

data = data.frame(x_axis = x_axis,confidence_low_yr_1 = confidence_low_yr_1,confidence_high_yr_1 = confidence_high_yr_1,confidence_low_yr_2 = confidence_low_yr_2,confidence_high_yr_2 = confidence_high_yr_2 )

ggplot(data, aes(x = x_axis))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = confidence_low_yr_1,ymax = confidence_high_yr_1))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = confidence_low_yr_2,ymax = confidence_high_yr_2))
```

Comment: If there are many years you can avoid typing out the `geom_ribbon` line each time and do it all at once with `ggplot(data, aes(x = x_axis)) + Map(function(l, h) geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = l, ymax = h)) ,
      data[grep('confidence_low', names(data))], 
      data[grep('confidence_high', names(data))])`

Answer (score 1):

```
graphics.off()
plot(1,
     xlim = range(x_axis),
     ylim = range(c(confidence_high_yr_1,
                    confidence_high_yr_2,
                    confidence_low_yr_1,
                    confidence_low_yr_2),
                  na.rm = TRUE),
     type = "n")
lines(x_axis, confidence_high_yr_1)
lines(x_axis, confidence_high_yr_2)
lines(x_axis, confidence_low_yr_1)
lines(x_axis, confidence_low_yr_2)
```

[image]